# Swapping two arrays in MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I need to swap two arrays where:

```
array1 = [10,9,8,7,6]
array2 = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

This is my assembler code:

```
.data    
    array1 DWORD 1, 2, 3, 4, 5    
    array2 DWORD 6, 7, 8, 9, 10    
.code        
main proc    
    mov     eax,array2+16
    mov     edx,array1
    mov     array1,eax
    mov     array2+16,edx
    mov     eax,array2+12
    mov     edx,array1+4
    mov     array1+4,eax
    mov     array2+12,edx
    mov     eax,array2+8
    mov     edx,array1+8
    mov     array1+8,eax
    mov     array2+8,edx
    mov     eax,array2+4
    mov     edx,array1+12
    mov     array1+12,eax
    mov     array2+4,edx
    mov     eax,array2
    mov     edx,array1+16
    mov     array1+16,eax
    mov     array2,edx
```

After I did all of this, I looked at my assignment instructions and apparently

> 0 Is the ONLY immediate/literal value that should be used in instructions.
>   I also can only use the `sub` and `mov` instructions.

I just need to know if I need to change anything.

Comment: Since you are using other immediate/literal values besides 0, yes, of course, you need to change something if you intend to comply with the assignment instructions. You need to learn to create a loop in assembly and index your array with a variable (in a register) rather than hard-coding it. And there's no way you can do it without any instructions but `mov`. Check the wording on that again.

Comment: I can only use sub and mov instructions

Answer (score 1):

The constraints for this task are:

- 0 is the only immediate/literal value that can be used
- `sub` and `mov` are the only instructions that can be used

Because the arrays follow each other in memory, I'll take 2 pointers that start at the second array.

```
array1 DWORD 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
             ^              ^
             |              |
             array1         array2 = ESI = EDI
```

The pointer that addresses the first array will pre-decrement and the pointer that addresses the second array will post-increment.

For decrementing, which is subtracting 1, I'll load the first value of the first array which happens to be 1. How convenient!
For incrementing, which is **adding 1** but also **subtracting -1**, I'll subtract that same 1 from the immediate 0 that I'm allowed to use.
Because the arrays hold **dwords**, it's enough to repeat the decrements/increments **4** times.

The swapping itself is done similar to what you did in your program.

```
; Setup
mov ecx, array1         ; ECX=1
mov edx, 0
sub edx, ecx            ; EDX=-1
mov esi, offset array2
mov edi, offset array2
; Swap array1[4] with array2[0]
sub esi, ecx            ; Pre-decrement on ESI (first array)
sub esi, ecx            ; Pre-decrement on ESI (first array)
sub esi, ecx            ; Pre-decrement on ESI (first array)
sub esi, ecx            ; Pre-decrement on ESI (first array)
mov eax, [esi]
mov ebx, [edi]
mov [edi], eax
mov [esi], ebx
sub edi, edx            ; Post-increment on EDI (second array)
sub edi, edx            ; Post-increment on EDI (second array)
sub edi, edx            ; Post-increment on EDI (second array)
sub edi, edx            ; Post-increment on EDI (second array)
; Swap array1[3] with array2[1]
...
```

Because of the severe constraints it's not possible to construct a loop. You'll have to rewrite that last block of code 5 times.

---

With a few lines of additional setup it's possible to assign `ECX=4` and `EDX=-4`. That way the pre-decrements and post-increments become but a single instruction each. This will shave off some 25 instructions.
Try for yourself before looking at below snippet!

> sub ecx, edx ; ECX=2
>  sub ecx, edx ; ECX=3
>  sub ecx, edx ; ECX=4
>  mov edx, 0
>  sub edx, ecx ; EDX=-4

Comment: `mov ecx, array1` uses the array address as a non-zero `disp32` encoded into the instruction.  This assignment is super-weird.  Are they only talking about *numeric* literals in the source code?  I guess it's *possible* that the intended solution was to use a known value from the array, but having a swap function that only works for specific data is super weird.  IDK, maybe this helps students understand that everything is just numbers?

Comment: `mov edx, 0`  could be `sub edx,edx` which most CPUs recognize as a zeroing idiom like `xor edx,edx`.  They might as well have disallowed numeric literals entirely (if students knew about zeroing idioms, which they probably don't), since I don't think it's useful to `mov [mem], 0` here.